# Obtaining latitude and longitude of multiple locations using Geopy

Tags: python, csv, geopy

I have been importing a csv dataset containing multiple addresses. I want to get the latitude and longitude of these places and write those to a new csv file along with the original address. I have been trying to use Geopy from python to achieve this. Given below is the code:

```
import csv
##from time import sleep

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

with open('D:/location_to_lat_lon/tolocate.csv', 'r') as fp:

        with open('D:/location_to_lat_lon/places_located.csv', 'w',newline='') as op:
            a = csv.writer(op)
            a.writerow(["Town","District","State","Country","Address","Latitude","Longitude"])
            for line in fp.readlines():
                geolocator = Nominatim()
                town_new = line.split(',')[0]
                district_new = line.split(',')[1]
                state_new = line.split(',')[2]
                country_new = line.split(',')[3]
                address_new = line.split(',')[4]
                location = geolocator.geocode(address_new)
                lat=location.latitude
                lon=location.longitude
                ##time.sleep(3)
              a.writerow([town_new,district_new,state_new,country_new,address_new,lat,lon])
```

However, every time I run this code I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 13, in
>   
>       lat=location.latitude AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

'

Comment: You have not considered the situation when `location = geolocator.geocode(address_new)` returns `None`

Comment: how do I handle that in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting that location can be None at times due to various reasons including the geocoding service not having geo spatial data for the given address.

simpley do

```
location = geolocator.geocode(address_new)
if location:
    lat=location.latitude
    lon=location.longitude
else :
    lat = None
    long = None
```

you could do `try, except` as well

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes Actual location i.e latitude and longitude are not available for a particular address. In that case you have to ignore such kind of address. In you code it should be something like this -

import csv

## from time import sleep

from geopy.geocoders import   Nominatim

with open('D:/location_to_lat_lon/tolocate.csv', 'r') as fp:

```
    with open('D:/location_to_lat_lon/places_located.csv', 'w',newline='') as op:
        a = csv.writer(op)
        a.writerow(["Town","District","State","Country","Address","Latitude","Longitude"])
        for line in fp.readlines():
            geolocator = Nominatim()
            town_new = line.split(',')[0]
            district_new = line.split(',')[1]
            state_new = line.split(',')[2]
            country_new = line.split(',')[3]
            address_new = line.split(',')[4]
            location = geolocator.geocode(address_new)
            ''' This will check if your given address has any latitude or longitude and if true then lat and lon will be assigned otherwise, both lat and lon will be 0. '''
            if location:
                lat=location.latitude
                lon=location.longitude
                ##time.sleep(3)
            else:
                lat = 0
                lon = 0
```

a.writerow([town_new,district_new,state_new,country_new,address_new,lat,lon])`